# Loop shows post 5 times in a query

Tags: loop, taxonomy

I'm trying get a list of all parent posts, based on a current taxonomy. It seems to work, but the list is repeating 5 times again.

This means, when there should be 3 posts in a list, I get 15 posts. Is there something I did wrong with the loop ?

```
    <ul>
<?php 
$terms = get_terms('taxonomy-name');
foreach($terms as $term) {
$posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => get_post_type(),
'post_parent' => 0,
'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'term-name',
                )
            ),
           ));

    foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
  <li>
  <?php the_title(); ?>
  </li>


  <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `wp_reset_postdata` but nowhere do you call `the_post` or `setup_postdata`, I'd also avoid overwriting or reusing the `$post` variable manually. I also strongly recommending that you indent your code, any decent editor will automagically do this for you, e.g. PHPStorm, SublimeText, Atom, etc

Comment: The reason your loop is showing so many times is because you are running a query (and loop) for each taxonomy term.  Guessing there are five members of that taxonomy.  A more performant approach is a single query and iterating through that object multiple times to filter your taxonomy terms.  You likely want `get_the_terms()` and then query based on that.

Answer (score 1):

`the_title()` is a template tag which relies on global state. Specifically `$post` global variable, holding current post instance.

While you *query* a set of posts, you never set up that global state for template tag to use.

Though in case you started with `get_posts()` it might be more convenient to leave global state alone altogether and just use `get_the_title()`, which can retrieve title of specific post on demand.

Answer (score -1):

thank you for anwer and recommend. I've done some code formation. I'm using dreamweaver, seems to be always a bit messy when working with PHP.

If I'm using **the_post();** instead, I get a loop, which repeats only twice. Better than before, but I think I'm doing something wrong. What do you exactly mean with avoiding the **$post** variable? Is it better to rename the post variable to exclude other conflicts?

```
<ul>
        <?php
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
foreach($terms as $term)
    {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => get_post_type() ,
        'post_parent' => 0,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => custom_taxonomies_terms_links() ,
            )
        ) ,
    ));
    foreach($posts as $post): ?>
        <li><!--Content here--></li>

        <?php endforeach; 
        the_post(); ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

The **custom_taxonomies_terms_links()** is a way, to get the current term of current taxonomy.

```
<?php

function custom_taxonomies_terms_links()
    {
    global $post, $post_id;
    $post = & get_post($post->ID);
    $post_type = $post->post_type;

    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy)
        {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
        if (!empty($terms))
            {
            foreach($terms as $term) $out.= $term->name;
            }
        }

    return $out;
    } ?>
```

Actually, I'm not sure, if this is the best or elegant way to do it like this.

Comment: Posting another question as an answer is a bit unusual?